# Both require() and double colons in a function

Tags: r

Is it good practice to use both `require()` and double colons in a function? Or is it sufficient to use only double colons?

**Examples**

*Alternative 1*

```
foo <- function(date) {
  require(lubridate)
  bar <- lubridate::wday(date)
  return(bar)
}
```

*Alternative 2*

```
foo <- function(date) {
  bar <- lubridate::wday(date)
  return(bar)
}
```

Comment: If you are using double colon I don't think you'll need `require` at all.

Comment: `::` gives more predictable results than `require()` - the latter makes assumptions about the search order for functions. This depends on what was loaded before, whether other functions on the search path have the same name, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `require()` and `::` are both ways to access the namespace of a package inside a function. They are not exactly equivalent. They provide different messages.

If you use `require()`, you get one set of messages. If the package exists, you get a message that it is attached.

```
  foo <- function(date) {
    require(lubridate)
    bar <- wday(date)
    return(bar)
  }
foo(as.Date("2020-1-31")) 
Attaching package: ‘lubridate’
[1] 6
```

If the package does not exist, you get an error.

```
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘lubridate’
```

If you use `::`, you get different behavior. The code is silent if it works.

```
 foo <- function(date) {
    bar <- lubridate::wday(date)
    return(bar)
  }
foo(as.Date("2020-1-31"))
[1] 6
```

If you do not have the package it generates a warning (not an error).

```
Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘lubridate’
```

Comment: Important: if you use `require()` on more than one package which contain a function of the same name, you witll  **still** have to use double-colon to specify the package that's lower on the sequence returned with `search()`